# ParquetSharp - Read columns into correct types without knowing the types in the file

Tags: c#, parquet, typed

I'm looking to make use of the parquet file type in C# to allow for interop with other data languages like Python and R used by others. I know the data I will be dealing with will be of type DataFrame (Python) and data.table (R). However at the time of reading the data I will not know the column types in the parquet data as I am looking to right a generic function to read/write parquet to/from Deedle Frames.

I've seen the doco [here](https://github.com/G-Research/ParquetSharp/blob/master/docs/Reading.md), but cannot seem to adapt it to perform the task. If I look in the metadata for a field I see the ElementType is of type Int32 but when I try

```
rowGroupReader.Column(0).LogicalReader<int>().ReadAll(numRows);  // 1
```

it complains that it cannot convert from Nullable to int. If I use

```
rowGroupReader.Column(0).LogicalReader<int?>().ReadAll(numRows);  // 2
```

I get a result as expected.
To make it generic I was using

```
private LogicalColumnReader<T> GetLogicalReader<T>(T dataType, ColumnReader reader)
{
    return reader.LogicalReader<T>();
}
```

Called by using

```
GetLogicalReader(rowGroupReader.Column(0).EntityType, rowGroupReader.Column(0))
```

as a method of effecting the code in (2) above.

How do I make this generic to cater for the nullable types desired? If I change the function to be of type T? I need to constrain T to be struct but then my call using ElementType will not compile.

I'm likely going about this the wrong way as a first attempt but I otherwise cannot see a use for the file format without a performant way of loading the data as typed correctly.

Comment: check and see if https://www.nuget.org/packages/ChoETL.Parquet helps. For more info  https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/5270332/Cinchoo-ETL-Parquet-Reader